# Drive a 8x16 segment LCD

Tags: lcd

I have an LCD with 16 segment pins and 8 backplanes. I have already figured out that a full cycle is 32ms, and know that the operating voltage is between 1v and 10v. I was wondering if there was a driver ic that I could use to drive the LCD with my Arduino.

(edit)
It is a raw LCD and has 24 pins going into it, 8 of which are com pins and 16 which are data pins. *It is NOT a 16 segment 8 digit display*. I have made a chart of what segment turns on according to the com-data combination. I have made my own labeling system for the segments to make the chart more organized. A-F represents the com pins and 1-16 represents the data pins.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Search for "LCD segment driver" at your favorite electronics distributor -- Mouser, Digikey, etc. -- and you'll find a lot of offerings.

To narrow down the options, I would first filter by the packages you are willing to work with and then start looking at the chips that support the largest number of segments.

Note you are unlikely to find anything suitable in a DIP package as most LCD drivers are SMD devices now.

Using the [NXP Product Selector](https://www.nxp.com/products/peripherals-and-logic/lcd-drivers/lcd-segment-drivers:MC_38538) and filtering "LCD character driver display format" for the "8 x ..." formats yields these possibilities:

[image]

Comment: Those appear to be 4-line dot-matrix display drivers. That's not what the OP's got. See https://www.osaelectronics.com/product/vf168/ for an example.

Comment: ok - answer modified

Comment: It looks like this is exactly what I need but I am pretty new to this and don't know exactly how I would implement this with my arduino

Comment: These drivers are complex devices, but after you have connected the proper voltage supplies they are just like any other I2C or SPI device. You'll have to write your own software, though, to send the right commands. Everything is in the datasheet. To gain more experience with interfacing an Arduino with a SPI device, you could try reading the MAX7219 datasheet and look at the Arduino libraries written for it. Not useful for driving your LCD display, but they way you operate with it will be very similar.